# Node JS JSON NaN

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse a JSON object with Node JS, when i'm printing the body of the response I'm getting the object correctly, but when I'm trying to get object.subsonic-response, I'm getting NaN. I've done a lot of research on Google, but I can't find how to get this to work.

Please help !

Thanks

My code:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url : host + view + logginParameters + actionParameters,
  headers: {
   'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  var object = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(object.subsonic-response);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Here is the JSON object:

```
{ 'subsonic-response': 
   { status: 'ok',
     version: '1.15.0',
     playlist: 
      { id: '39',
        name: 'Smoothie !',
        comment: '',
        owner: 'william',
        public: true,
        songCount: 24,
        duration: 5392,
        created: '2015-11-19T17:08:02.874Z',
        changed: '2016-03-27T04:10:19.753Z',
        coverArt: 'pl-39',
        entry: [Object]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't use hyphens in member names, change it to object['subsonic-response']

Comment: Omg ! I still have a lot to learn ! Thanks a lot, it's working now ! :)

Comment: Not a problem. Good luck. May be worth marking @Michael Ratliff's answer as correct for anyone stumbling across this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is being parsed by node like this `(object.subsonic) - response` which is `NaN`.  What you want is `object['subsonic-response']`.